# Nested try blocks - does this have a use?

Tags: java, try-catch

I have come across a piece of code that looks like this

```
try
{
    try (SomeResource res = new SomeResource())
    {
        // "\(o.o)/" *BOO*
    }
}
catch (SomeException e)
{
    e.letsNotIgnoreTheException();
}
```

I could not think of a single reason to use two try-blocks. No one else I asked could think of one either.

I am left to wonder, whether this is simply 
a methode in need of some refactoring, or if there actually is some use to the outer try (especially since I found this several times, but then again, 
someone might have simply misunderstood the try-with-resources).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given there are no extra flow-of-control or try constructs in your real code, your code is equivalent to this:

```
    try (SomeResource res = new SomeResource()) {
        // "\(o.o)/" *BOO*
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        e.letsNotIgnoreThisException();
    }
```

Please note that:

- try-with-resources executes `res.close()` before exception handling
- therefore `e.letsNotIgnoreThisException()` gets called *after* `res.close()`
- any other exceptions thrown by `*BOO*` line must be handled (i.e. caught or declared) appropriately

The key line explaining the order of execution of resource closing and exception handling in try-with-resources is described here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

quote:

**Note:** *A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been closed.*

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to two articles about try-catch and try without catch

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Answer (score 0):

If the outside try-catch has nothing inside besides the inner try, then it's unnecessary since you can combine them into one. However, if the outer try-catch has something else in it, the semantics may be different.

Answer (score 0):

**Disproved:**

This performs differently than a single try block - the try-with-resources translates into closing the resource in a finally block, which executes *after* catch blocks, whereas the try-with-resources in a nested try block executes *before* outer catch blocks.

It could be useful if you want to close the `SomeResource` resource before the catch block is performed.

For example, if you were writing something into a file and on error wanted to delete that file contents and write an error message into the same file instead (dummy example, I know), you could do this by closing the resource first, then deleting the file and writing the error within a new stream / resource.

Comment: Jiri, that was my first presumption, but I tested it and this is incorrect - try-with-resources is *not* the same as a finally block, resources get closed **before** catch and finally. Please see the text "any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been closed." in the oracle documentation...

Comment: @vikingsteve I stand corrected, thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: No worries. This actually changed my understanding, since try-with-resources is not *"technically"* the same as a finally block, although it shouldn't matter in most circumstances. I learned something new today also :)

Answer (score 0):

When accessing a database this pattern occurrs often - primarily to ensure resources are closed properly but also to deal with errors while processing each record without stopping the query.

```
    try {
        ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
        try {
            // Each row.
            while (rs.next()) {
                // Handle each record.
                try {
                    // One row.
                } catch (SomeException se) {
                    // Deal with exception when processing the row so we do not abort the whole query.
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            // Perhaps database connection went down during the iteration.
        } finally {
            // Remember to close - whatever happens.
            rs.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Probably the query is malformed or something.
        log.error("failed", ex);
    }
```